# Cannot create simple file with puppet locally or at client node

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I have Puppet v8.5.1 running on Ubuntu 22.04. I have a puppetmaster and puppet agent node communicating with each other. Now I created a simple "helloworld" under the production modules path (/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/helloworld/) and a manifests directory as well. Inside said manifests directory, I have this simple init.pp file:

```
class helloworld {
  file { '/tmp/foobar.txt':
    ensure  => file,
    mode    => '0644',
    content => 'Hello World \n';
  }
}
```

Now when I attempt to run the following "puppet apply" command from the puppetmaster, it shows only the following and there is no file being created in the /tmp folder:

```
root@sandbox-puppetmaster:~# puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/helloworld/manifests/init.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for sandbox-puppetmaster.ddc.local in environment production in 0.02 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

Over on the puppet node, I ran the command:

```
root@sandbox-node1:/tmp# puppet agent --test
Info: Using environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Notice: Requesting catalog from sandbox-puppetmaster.ddc.local:8140 (10.20.27.7)
Notice: Catalog compiled by sandbox-puppetmaster.ddc.local
Info: Caching catalog for sandbox-node1
Info: Applying configuration version '1709918930'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

And no file shows up in /tmp either.

What is it I am doing wrong?

It should be putting a simple file called "foobar.txt" in the /tmp directory.

Comment: `puppet apply` would have no effect on that manifest because it contains only a `class` definition. There are many possible easons `puppet agent -t` would have no effect. The first reason to check would be the node classification and associated catalog for your Ubuntu server should declare that class `helloworld`.

Comment: Actually, I found the issue from the Puppet Slack channel. I had the right init.pp in the right modules folder, but forgot to put the site.pp file in the manifests folder. The site.pp file needed to contain the actual call to the class in the init.pp file, thus it wasn't getting called.

Comment: Could you introduce some sort of syntax error in your manifest? The `sandbox‑node1` Puppet run should _fail_ then.